# WebAssembly Performance Optimization by Combining DLLs

Tags: c#, .net, dll, blazor, blazor-webassembly

We are using web assembly for our retail website and it's really slow on the first load. When you first visit the site, it takes a long while before the page loads and is ready. But if you refresh the page, the load time is a lot faster.  This is killing us with new customers.

I did `inspect` most of the performance hits are against the web assembly dlls that are being loaded into the browser from the server.  There are a lot of them.  While their size is small, each connection to fetch them is slow in of itself - death by thousand stings.  When the page is refreshed, or visited for the second time on the same browser, the page loads fast but that's because all those dlls are cached and ready to go.  This is a big problem for mobile where the network fluctuates.

Is there a way to combine all the required dlls into ONE dll for wasm so we won't get with repeated connection performance hit?  Something like WebPack for dlls?

Comment: Did you try release mode? There are a lot of optimizations: tree-shaking, folding etc.

Comment: My first question, is WASM the best choice here? Why not use server side? Second, did you ensure that only the required DLLs to run the WASM app are included?